# A better way to preserve static lists between postbacks in MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm populating a list in the viewmodel from the database, and then using this list to populate a dropdownlist on the view.  If I submit the form, the model is passed to the server, and if the model is invalid, the model is sent back to the page.  Now, there doesn't seem to be a way to send the list or preserve it in any way, so i'm basically retrieving the list again from the database on postback, so that it gets sent back to the view and can be re-bound to the dropdown list.

It seems odd to me that I have to query the database each time to view the same static data.  I can cache the query, but isn't there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Repopulating the `SelectList` in the POST method is exactly what you should be doing.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways to skin this common scenario.  Here are some approaches:

1. Instead of using a full page post-back, use javascript to
   "asynchronously" submit the form to the controller, and handle the
   response.  This should be the preferred method. See lots of
   examples: [https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mvc+ajax+post](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mvc%20ajax%20post).
2. Static `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property/field in your view model that is populated/re-populated when appropriate.  This is the most quick and dirty approach.
3. Create a "serialized" property of your `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property in the view model, and hide it within the form.  The getters and setters of these properties will serialize and deserialize the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.  If you are completely set against AJAX and statics in your server, this technique will work:

E.g (this example uses [Newtonsoft.JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) [get it here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/))

**View Model**

```
class MyViewModel
{

    public string MyItemFromSelection { get;set;}

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MySelectList
    {
        get
        {
            return mySelectList;
        }
        set
        {
            mySelectList = value;
            // serialize to a json string
            SelectListSerialized = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
        }
    }
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> mySelectList;

    public string SelectListSerialized
    {
        get
        {
            return selectListSerialized;
        }
        set
        {
            selectListSerialized = value;
            if(MySelectList == null)
            {
                // if the MySelectList  haven't been set, deserialize the string to populate MySelectList
                MySelectList = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<SelectListItem>>(value);
            }
        }
    }
    string selectListSerialized;
}
```

**Razor**

```
@model MyViewModel
<form>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectListSerialized)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyItemFromSelection, Model.MySelectList)
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use TempData if you want to preserve the data between 2 requests.

Fetch the data from db and store them in TempData.
When you do the second call to the controller, use the data from the same tempdata.

No extra db call will be needed this time.

Also, if you want to again keep and store this tempdata value in next request , you can simply use "keep" feature of tempdata for it.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that it is inefficient for the list to be posted back to the server when the server really just cares about the selected value.

If you are concerned about having to send the same list to the same user each time, you could have the client caching the list using something like local storage.

Of course, this means that each users still has to get the list the first time, so on the server you will still need to build up the list. If it is something that doesn't change often, I would use your approach of caching the list to prevent a database hit.